# Bootstrap affix events

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, affix

I'm having difficulty hooking affix events. I've got alert in each event but non shows up when page is scrolled.

e.g.:

`$('#nav').on('affix.bs.affix', function () {alert('affix.bs.affix');});`

jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93ssB/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your fiddle is using Bootstrap 2 - affix events only work in Bootstrap 3: http://www.bootply.com/122023

Comment: Thank you Skelly, that explains it all.

Comment: OK, I thought I had Bootstrap 3 in my original code and it still didn't work. Bootstrap affix events only work in 3.1.x and not older (e.g. 3.0.3): [bootply.com/122081](http://www.bootply.com/122081)

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question (thanks Skelly):

Bootstrap `affix` requires Bootstrap 3.  Bootstrap 2 does not support this.